# Integrating titandb with sigma.js

Tags: titan, sigma.js, linkurious

I am new to titandb. As per the titandb documentation, there is predefined graph (GraphOfTheGods). I want to visualize the graph using sigma.js or any other. For this purpose, I want to integrate titandb with sigma.js.

Please help me to integrate titandb with any graph visualization software.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say if you are building an application that visualizes graphs or you just want to do some analysis of Titan using a graph visualization technique.  If you are building an application and are then using a library like sigma.js (or other viz libs), then you'd need to build some server application around Titan to utilize sigma.js.  The "how" you do that is a massively broad question.

On the other hand, if you are doing some standalone visualization for analytic purposes, you have a few specific options.  You can use a graph visualization toolkit like [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/) or [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) for this purpose.  Open up your Titan graph with the Gremlin Console and then export the graph to a format accepted by those tools - typically [GraphML](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#_graphml_reader_writer):

```
final Graph graph = TinkerFactory.createModern();
graph.io(IoCore.graphml()).writeGraph("tinkerpop-modern.xml");
```

The above example uses TinkerGraph but would work equally well with a Titan `Graph` instance.  You could then import that file into the tool.

You could also use the new [TinkerPop 3.x Gephi Plugin](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#gephi-plugin) for the Gremlin Console which allows you some interactive capabilities and a nicer workflow than export/import.  That is the preferred method in 3.x.

Comment: when I am running second command, it is throwing error as No such property: graph for class: groovysh_evaluate. please help me resolve this.

Comment: if you are using the console, then don't declare your variables.  just do `graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()`